# Create chained methods in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chaining

Is it possible to create chained methods that are asynchronous like this in node.js

```
File.create('file.jpg').rename('renamed.jpg').append('Hello World')
```

That is to say non-blocking.

Comment: If it's non-blocking, shouldn't there be a callback function passed in somewhere?

Comment: @Matthew: Yeah it should. So I wonder if there is some way to create a method chaining that is asynch. Maybe with a library that could handle it automatically somehow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You basically want to *abstract* the asynchronous nature of the file-handling operations on your API.

It can be done, I would recommend you to give a look to the following article:

- [Asynchronous method queue chaining in JavaScript](http://www.dustindiaz.com/async-method-queues/)

The article was written by Dustin Diaz, who currently works on the [@anywhere JavaScript API](http://platform.twitter.com/js-api.html), and he does exactly what you want, using a using a simple Queue implementation, a fluent interface can be created, being independent of any callback.

The *asynchronicity* is hidden and it is handled internally by your API, it's a nice and simple technique.

Comment: The @anywhere link is dead :(

Comment: +1 for a library. I did come across https://github.com/FuturesJS/FuturesJS that has a `chainify` API, but can't find info on how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Sure, like any JavaScript, you just return an object that has that method.

One possible layout (among many).

```
var File = new (function() 
{ 
  this.create = function(str) 
  { 
    return this; 
  } 
  this.rename = function(str) 
  { 
    return this; 
  } 
})();
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell you that the code has to be asynchronous in Node.js. I have edited the post.